# Поменять данные между таблицами mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli, mariadb

Есть две одинаковых по структуре таблицы, в одной хранятся одни данные, в другой другие.
Как поменять данные между ними местами?

Что-то приближенное:

```
INSERT INTO db2.tb SELECT * FROM db1.tb;
```

Но это заменит данные в db2 на db1, мне необходимо их поменять, пробовал переименовать но при уже созданных таблицах переименовывать не хочет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RENAME TABLE db1 TO dbTemp, db2 To db1, dbTemp TO db2;
```

Comment: Если имеются внешние ключи и/или триггеры - результат будет далёк от требуемого.

Answer (score 0):

Если имеются внешние ключи, то надо переносить данные через временную таблицу.

Если имеются ещё и триггеры, их придётся удалить перед обменом и пересоздать после.

```
CREATE TABLE test.tempTable SELECT * FROM db2.tb;
TRUNCATE db2.tb;
INSERT INTO db2.tb SELECT * FROM db1.tb;
TRUNCATE db1.tb;
INSERT INTO db1.tb SELECT * FROM test.tempTable;
DROP test.tempTable;
```

Если количество записей в таблицах невелико, можно `test.tempTable` сделать `ENGINE = Memory`, это снизит потребность в дисковых операциях.

Поскольку имеются внешние ключи на таблицы - надо отключить их проверку на время выполнения переноса. Правда, есть опасность потом не включить, если данные не проходят контроль.

Не надо делать временную таблицу TEMPORARY - если посередь процесса что-то засбоит, будет мучительно больно.